# Incorrect Texbox Focus

Tags: vb.net, textbox, focus

I have a series of textboxes and I wish for the first one that has no text to have the focus and have used the following.

```
Private Sub Set_Box_Focus()
    Dim txt2 As TextBox
    For L = 0 To MaxLetters - 1
        txt2 = panGrid.Controls("txt" & L.ToString & CurrentTry.ToString)
        If txt2.Text = "" Then
            txt2.Focus()
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Unfortunately this is not working.  If the second one is empty the third one has the focus, if the third is enpty fifth has focus, if the fourth is empty seventh has focus.
I have tried many things without success.  The only one which works is inserting a msgbox.

```
Private Sub Set_Box_Focus()
    Dim txt2 As TextBox
    For L = 0 To MaxLetters - 1
        txt2 = panGrid.Controls("txt" & L.ToString & CurrentTry.ToString)
        If txt2.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox(txt2.Name)
            txt2.Focus()
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

This is obviously not useable but does show that the correct box is been chosen. I have come across using the msgbox to solve a problem before and have usually gone arround it.
Any ideas?

Comment: When you debug the first code, you break on `txt2.Focus()`, check the name, it's correct, it focuses, exit the for loop, then back to running and the wrong textbox has focus, is that correct?

Comment: My question would be how are you calling this method?  Are you sure it's not being called multiple times moving the focus to the next text box each time?

Comment: Correct.  It is called on form loading and correctly focuses on the first box.  It is then called by a button click.

Comment: The problem seems to be caused by the some of the boxes being unabled and / or having a changed background colour - though why this should affect the result I am still trying to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that those are the only `TextBoxes` in that container and that the z-order is set appropriately, you can just do this:

```vb
panGrid.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox).
                 FirstOrDefault(Function(tb) tb.TextLength = 0)?.
                 Select()
```

If the z-order is not set appropriately, use the *Document Outline* window to change that.

Note that that code calls `Select` rather than `Focus`, just as the documentation clearly states.

Comment: Thank you - but have exactly the same effect.  The textboxes are add row by row programically.

Comment: I tried FOCUS, SELECT and ACTIVECONTROL with the same effect.  If  N is the first empty box it is focusing on box N+(N-1)

Comment: @Tony, you need to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question accordingly because the code I provided works perfectly for me so it is obviously something specific that you are doing that you haven't told us about.

Answer (score 0):

After 3 days it is driving me batty so I am posting the whole form so that it can be run and hopefuly someone can point out to me what an idiot I am!

```
Public Class Form1
Dim Letters() As String
Dim MaxLetters = 5
Dim MaxTries As Integer = 5
Dim CurrentTry As Integer = 1

Dim PanGrid As Panel
Dim btnCheck As Button

Dim Word As String = "PLANS"

Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

    Me.Font = New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif,", 10, FontStyle.Bold)

    Dim aPan As New Panel
    With aPan
        .Parent = Me
        .Top = 40
        .Left = 40
        .Visible = True
    End With
    PanGrid = aPan

    Dim aButton As New Button
    With aButton
        .Visible = True
        .Text = "Check"
    End With
    btnCheck = aButton
    AddHandler btnCheck.Click, AddressOf btnCheck_Click

End Sub

Public Sub Load_Grid()
    Dim HW As Integer
    Dim TabInx As Integer = 0

    btnCheck.Parent = Me

    PanGrid.Controls.Clear()
    CurrentTry = 1

    For T = 1 To MaxTries
        For L = 1 To MaxLetters
            Dim Txt As New TextBox
            With Txt
                .TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center
                .Font = New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif,", 20, FontStyle.Italic)
                HW = .Height
                .Width = HW
                .Top = (T - 1) * HW
                .Left = (L - 1) * HW
                .MaxLength = 1
                .Parent = PanGrid
                .Text = ""
                .Name = "txt" & L.ToString & T.ToString
                .Visible = True
                .TabIndex = TabInx
                .Tag = False
                TabInx += 1
                .Enabled = (T = CurrentTry)
            End With
            AddHandler Txt.KeyPress, AddressOf TextBox_KeyPress
            AddHandler Txt.TextChanged, AddressOf TextBox_TextChanged
        Next
    Next

    With PanGrid
        .Width = MaxLetters * HW
        .Height = MaxTries * HW
    End With

    With btnCheck
        .Height = HW
        .Top = PanGrid.Top
        .Left = PanGrid.Left + PanGrid.Width
        .Show()
    End With

    ReDim Letters(MaxLetters)
    For i = 0 To MaxLetters - 1
        Letters(i) = Word.Substring(i, 1)
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim S As String = sender.text
    If S <> "" Then
        SendKeys.Send("{TAB}")
    End If
    For L = 1 To MaxLetters
        Dim txt As TextBox = PanGrid.Controls("txt" & L.ToString & CurrentTry.ToString)
        txt.SelectionLength = 0
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs)
    Dim KC As Integer = Asc(e.KeyChar)
    If KC >= 97 And KC <= 122 Then
        KC -= 32
    ElseIf KC >= 65 And KC <= 90 Then

    Else
        KC = 0
        If sender.text <> "" Then
            KC = Asc(sender.text)
        End If
    End If

    sender.Text = ""

    e.KeyChar = Chr(KC)

End Sub

Private Sub btnCheck_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    'Value in every box
    For L = 1 To MaxLetters
        Dim Txt As TextBox = PanGrid.Controls("txt" & L.ToString & CurrentTry.ToString)
        If Txt.Text = "" Then
            Txt.Select()
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next

    'Check if any letters match in correct order
    Dim Cnt As Integer = 0
    For L = 1 To MaxLetters
        Dim Txt As TextBox = PanGrid.Controls("txt" & L.ToString & CurrentTry.ToString)
        If Txt.Text = Letters(L - 1) Then
            Txt.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
            Letters(L - 1) = "-"
        End If
        If Letters(L - 1) = "-" Then Cnt += 1
    Next

    'If all letters have not been matched
    If Cnt <> MaxLetters Then
        'Check if any letters match in any order
        For L = 1 To MaxLetters
            Dim Txt As TextBox = PanGrid.Controls("txt" & L.ToString & CurrentTry.ToString)
            For L2 = 1 To MaxLetters
                If Txt.Text = Letters(L2 - 1) Then
                    If Txt.BackColor <> Color.LightGreen Then Txt.BackColor = Color.LightBlue
                End If
            Next
        Next

        CurrentTry += 1

        For T = 1 To MaxTries
            For L = 1 To MaxLetters
                Dim Txt As TextBox = PanGrid.Controls("txt" & L.ToString & T.ToString)
                With Txt
                    .Enabled = (T = CurrentTry)
                    If T = CurrentTry Then
                        Dim Txt2 As TextBox = PanGrid.Controls("txt" & L.ToString & (T - 1).ToString)
                        If Txt2.BackColor = Color.LightGreen Then
                            Txt.Text = Txt2.Text
                            Txt.BackColor = Txt2.BackColor
                                .Enabled = False
                            End If
                        End If
                          End With
            Next
        Next

        If CurrentTry = MaxTries Then
            btnCheck.Hide()
        Else
            Set_Box_Focus()
            btnCheck.Top = (CurrentTry - 1) * btnCheck.Height + PanGrid.Top
        End If
    Else
        btnCheck.Hide()
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Set_Box_Focus()
    Dim txt As TextBox
    For L = 1 To MaxLetters
        txt = PanGrid.Controls("txt" & L.ToString & CurrentTry.ToString)
        If Not (txt.BackColor = Color.LightGreen) Then
            'The correct textbox is chosen but the wrong one is selected
            txt.Select()
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

End Class